# Three.js - Importing an OBJ model, half of the triangles are transparent

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, rendering

I am having a problem with an obj file exported from Rhino3D into obj: half of the triangles composing some part of the model are transparent.
The models seems good in the 3D editor.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'table.obj', function ( object ) {

    object.scale.x=0.1;
    object.scale.y=0.1;
    object.scale.z=0.1;
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            child.material.map = texture;
            child.material.side = THREE.Doubleside;

        }

    } );

    object.position.y = - 80;
    scene.add( object );

}, onProgress, onError );
```

I get no errors. Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

When exporting from Rhino3D, checking "Map Z on Y" fixed the problem!